# Changing Existing Cell Value with Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

I am working on some code trying to change cells in an existing .xlsx file.

Therefore, I am looking for all empty "None" fields in column A and tryiing to copy a value.
Unfortunately, the value of the cell will not be overwritten by following lines.
Only if I put in clear numbers e.g. 18, I will get the right result, but wants to iterate.

```
import openpyxl

path= 'mypath/Python/Excel_test.xlsx'

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook( path )
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Tabelle1')

i=1
for row in worksheet.iter_rows(values_only=True): 
    if row[0]!=None:
        text=row[0]
        print(row)
    else:
        worksheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value=text
        print(row)
    i=i+1

workbook.save('test.xlsx')
```

Thanks a lot
Dominik

Comment: This runs correctly as you've explained your desired output

Comment: Hi Jezza_99 - unfortunately not. 
```
worksheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value=text
```
is not working for me - i will not work, only if I fill in explicit numbers

Within this code, the line is never doing its job

Comment: If I do like in the example code for line 20 it will be - ('None', 'None','Actual')
Result which I want to have if i put ...row=20, column... instead row=i ('Project','None',Actual')

Comment: Could you provide an example of the table you are using please?